# Use OIDC in Swagger UI with Quarkus

Tags: swagger, keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

I have Quarkus & Swagger UI setup to use my keycloak server (OIDC)

```
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme=oidc
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-name=Keycloak
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oidc-open-id-connect-url=https://someurl.com/auth/realms/arealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
quarkus.swagger-ui.oauth2-redirect-url=http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html
```

I also have an endpoint setup to accept authorization

```java
@Path("/health")
@Authenticated
public class ReactiveHealthResource {

    @Inject
    SecurityIdentity identity;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello RESTEasy Reactive";
    }
}
```

In Swagger UI I can see the Authorize button and I can click it, fill in the authorization_code client details and authenticate via keycloak and get redirected back to Swagger UI.

When I then click to try an endpoint, I get a 401 error and the Bearer token header for the OIDC auth isn't sent with the request.

Have I missed a step or a setting?

Comment: You missed api specification.

Comment: do you mean like the config values or in the code itself? @JanGaraj

Comment: I recommend you to check what json produced by your application for Swagger UI and compare it with OpenAPI v3 specification docs (like https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/). Also check whether your Swagger UI version supports mentioned specification, as far as I remember some times ago Swagger UI had some troubles with OIDC.

Note that OpenAPIv3 is a specification for web-service definition, while Swager UI just draws a beautiful UI for this web service by its OpenAPI definition, so Swagger may not implement some parts of this specification yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Path("/health")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Keycloak")
@Authenticated
public class ReactiveHealthResource {
```

Adding the @SecurityRequirement informs Swagger UI of the authentication to use

Answer (score 1):

Alex I had the same problem as you and I managed to solve it as follows.

```
@Path("/health")
@Authenticated
@SecuritySchemes(value = {
    @SecurityScheme(securitySchemeName = "openIdConnectUrl",
            type = SecuritySchemeType.OPENIDCONNECT,
            openIdConnectUrl = "https://someurl.com/auth/realms/arealm/.well-known/openid-configuration")}
)
public class ReactiveHealthResource {

    @Inject
    SecurityIdentity identity;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    @SecurityScheme(securitySchemeName = "api_key",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.APIKEY,
        apiKeyName = "api_key",
        in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello RESTEasy Reactive";
    }
}
```

I also commented out the *smallrye-openapi* properties file settings

```
# quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme=oidc
# quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-name=Keycloak
# quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oidc-open-id-connect-url=https://someurl.com/auth/realms/arealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
```